# Re-route/Redirect localhost from Windows VM to host machine

Tags: windows, proxy, localhost, virtualbox

Hello guys I have a VM with Windows 10 installed on my MAC and I am running my project frontend and backend on my Mac (host machine). I would like to be able to access the project on my VM to see how the website loads on the IE11.

I know that you can access the frontend only by passing the ip of the host, so 10.0.2.2 but my backend is pointing to localhost.

So the backend is not able to hit my host machine, but it is trying to hit the localhost from the guest machine.

I tried to change the hosts file and flush the dns cache as many people suggested but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have being searching around and I found that to re-route the localhost and point it to the host machine I need to setup a proxy on the guest terminal.

So, I have redirected the localhost:8080 that is the address of my server on my host machine to the 10.0.2.2:8080 that is the api of my host machine in the VM network.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8080 connectaddress=10.0.2.2 connectport=8080
```